# Работа с БД на mssql для веб-приложения на php

Tags: javascript, php, html

Имеется БД на mssql (в которой хранится большое кол-во информации), необходимо разработать под базу веб-приложение, для отображения списка документов (менять всё под mysql не вариант, спрашивал, вопрос отклонили, сказали что хотят остаться на mssql). И тут столкнулся с нехваткой знаний в данной области. Подскажите пожалуйста, какими средствами лучше реализовать работу с БД именно на mssql(по типу Node.js, но к сожалению не могу найти нормальной информации) и как это можно сделать?

Comment: sequelize. ORM, которая выполняет работу с БД за вас. Посмотрите, возможно подойдет

Comment: Спасибо, за помощь

Answer (score 1):

Сделать это можно на PHP, скачав драйвер с официального сайта Microsoft (https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/connect/php/download-drivers-php-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15).
Качаете пак, закидываете dll своей версии на сервер, в php ini разблокируйте dll.
Ниже простой пример моего подключения:

```
<?php
   // Подключение к бд
   $servername = 'DESKTOP-9PGF2CL'; // instance и порт - необязательные параметры
   $options = [
      'Database' => 'db',  // наименование бд
      "CharacterSet"=>"UTF-8" // установим кодировку
      /* 'UID' => 'username', // имя пользователя, имеющего доступ к БД
      'PWD' => 'password', // пароль */
   ];
   $conn = sqlsrv_connect($servername, $options);
   //Проверка подключения
   if( $conn === false ) {
      die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors() ));
   }
   else{

   }
   //Достаем данные из таблицы
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM [db].[dbo].[Table]";
   $stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);
   //Формируем массив данных объектов
   while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ){
      $result[] = $row;
   }
   ?>
```

У меня PHP 8.1.6

Comment: Добавлю, что выйти на эту ссылку можно из документации к php [pdo](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/ref.pdo-dblib.php). Документация php вообще крутая, всегда стоит заглянуть в неё.